# no cloneType for Mem?

Tags: chisel

I'm wrapping a block of Mem in a fairly generic module called "bank" and instantiating it in a Vec as follows:

val rams = Vec.fill( 100 ) { Module( new bank ).io }

So far so good.  I'm running into problems when I connect the signals.  If I connect the vector of modules' signals directly to vectors of signals, like so:

```
rams(i).in := io.ins(i)
io.outs(i) := rams(i).out
```

...and so forth, I get no errors.

If I connect them in a non-trivial pattern, however, such as to a crossbar, I start getting a weird error that appears to refer to the Mem wrapper I call "bank":

"Parameterized Bundle class ascenium.bank$$anon$1 needs cloneType method."

This error is specifically a Chisel error.  Can anybody tells me what it means and how to fix it?

I can provide source code if need be.

Comment: I tried replacing Mem() with Vec(Reg()) and got no joy.  Same error.

Answer (score 1):

Errors like this can usually be addressed by adding a cloneType method to classes you define:

```
class MyModule extends Module
{
  // Your class definition here
  override def cloneType = new MyModule.asInstanceOf[this.type]
}
```

Comment: This causes the error "not found: value MyModule".  Evidently you can't refer to a class within itself.

Comment: Looking at the Chisel source code I see: 1) this syntax is wrong and should be something like: override def cloneType: this.type = new MyModule.asInstanceOf[this.type]; 2) cloneTypes appear to be associated with Bundles, not Modules, so in any case, putting it in Module would be wrong.